# Script to delete files older than 30days

Tags: linux, redhat, shell, syslog

Shell script should not delete any files under* root dir*. My* path will be like 
/export/home/ftp/ ...

I did some research and figured out the way for finding and deleting the files older than 30 days from a specific path, using find and exec commands.

*find /export/home/ftp/ -type f -mtime +30 -exec rm -f {} \;

But according to the requirement I want to delete console.log and server.log only from that directory and exclude the remaining files.

Please help me out in this issue.

Comment: So then is your title inaccurate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you really need to be using `find` in order to recurse through subdirectories:

```
find /export/home/ftp \( -name console.log -or -name server.log \) -mtime +30 -exec rm -f {} +
```

Comment: You could make it a little more efficient by adding -maxdepth 1 so that it doesn't actually recurse since you know which two files you want to check exactly.

Comment: I always forget that find has a `-delete` option. So let's amend that outright to: `find /export/home/ftp -maxdepth 1 \( -name console.log -or -name server.log \) -mtime +30 -delete`

Comment: could u pls tell any link to study shell script easily.

Answer (score 10):

If you just need to remove the old server.log and console.log every month you can also use `logrotate` which is most likely already running under RHEL. A config snippet like this will work in `/etc/logrotate.d/*.conf` or wherever the config files are located on your system.

```
# rotate server.log and console.log every month
# delete, not compress, old file

/export/home/ftp/server.log /export/home/ftp/console.log {
    monthly
    rotate 0
}
```

A custom monthly cron, as suggested above, will also work well. In fact, since logrotate is run from cron, you could consider this a cron extension of sorts. HTH.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use a monthly cron?

@monthly /usr/bin/rm -f console.log
@monthly /usr/bin/rm -f server.log

It would definitely be safer then doing things with find.

Answer (score 0):

Check this handy tool from debian [tmpreaper](http://annoyingtechnicaldetails.wordpress.com/tag/tmpreaper/)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to use xargs, which is apparently more efficient — http://www.sunmanagers.org/pipermail/summaries/2005-March/006255.html

So you could do something like this:

```
find /export/home/ftp -maxdepth 1 \( -name console.log -or -name server.log \) -mtime +30 | xargs -O -r rm
```