# how to rotate console.log in every day...?

Tags: linux, redhat, scripting, shell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Script to delete files older than 30days](https://serverfault.com/questions/212751/script-to-delete-files-older-than-30days)

My hard disk suddenly became full and I searched around until I finally discovered that a "console.log.9" file buried in Library/Logs/Console/myname/ was 112 Gigs !

I couldn't able to open and check it properly.

I did some research and figured out the way for finding and deleting the log files older than 30 days from a specific path, using find and exec commands.

find /export/home/ftp ( -name console.log -or -name server.log ) -mtime +30 -exec rm -f {} +

But i want to rotate console.log in daily wise and Is any shell script to rotate the console.log daily.

Please help me out in this issue.

Comment: Duplicate post: http://serverfault.com/questions/212751/script-to-delete-files-older-than-30days

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a file to `/etc/logrotate.d`, containing something like

```
/export/home/ftp/console.log {
  rotate 7
  daily
  compress
  missingok
  notifempty
}
```

Comment: +1, logrotate was built for this, no need to muck around with shell scripts.

Comment: i have one doubt,is log rotate affects the currently running jboss application.

Comment: Try using the `copytruncate` directive